# Duplicate entries List View with Generic Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, generics, adapter

I have a generic adapter to use with all kind of listView but I get duplicated items in a ListView. When I'm Scrolling back and down sometimes changes the item order. There is some threads about that but not with a generic adapter. I know Android reuse the Ui object but the view in getView is always null (said android Studio)

Here is my code about adapter :

Interface :

```
public interface Adaptable {
    public View buildView(View v, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent);
}
```

BaseView Class :

```
public abstract class BaseView<T,E> implements Adaptable{
    private static final String TAG = "BaseView";
    protected int layoutId;
    protected T viewHolder;
    protected E entity;
    public BaseView(){

    }

    public BaseView(E entity, int layoutId){
        this.entity = entity;
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
    }

    protected void invokeView(View v){
        try {
            Field fs[] = viewHolder.getClass().getFields();
            for (Field f : fs) {
                InvokeView a = f.getAnnotation(InvokeView.class);
                int id = a.viewId();
                Log.d(TAG, "field name: " + f.getName());
                Log.d(TAG, "view id: " + id);
                Log.d(TAG, "class: " + f.getClass());
                f.set(viewHolder, v.findViewById(id));

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public View buildView(View v, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        // load the view
        if (null == v) {
            v = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
            // get the view
            invokeView(v);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (T) v.getTag();
        }

        // binding logic data to view
        mappingData(viewHolder, entity, v.getContext());

        return v;
    }

    protected abstract void mappingData(T viewHolder, E entity, Context mContext);
}
```

Custom adapter class :

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Adaptable> items;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public CustomListAdapter(List<?> items, Context c) {
    this.items = (List<Adaptable>) items;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return items.get(position).buildView(convertView, inflater, parent);    }
}
```

InvokeView Interface :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface InvokeView {
    int viewId();
}
```

Here how I set it in my activity :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        ListView listViewPlaces = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listLocality);
        List<PlacesView> lstPlaceView = new ArrayList<PlacesView>();
        ArrayList<PlaceModel> listPlaces = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("listPlaces");
        for (int i = 0; i < listPlaces.size(); i++)
        {
            Log.d("id", listPlaces.get(i).getId());
            PlacesView mv = new PlacesView(listPlaces.get(i), R.layout.list_row_places);
            lstPlaceView.add(mv);
        }
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(lstPlaceView, rootView.getContext());
        listViewPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

If anyone have an idea.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You should use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView) instead of the `ListView`. Implementation is  easier because the ReciclerView handles reusing Views by itself, then you should stop having that issue.

Comment: Okay, I will try and keep you in touch.

Comment: what is BaseView for? what actually do you want to achieve in it? why do you want to get fields of viewHolder: `viewHolder.getClass().getFields()`

Comment: @NahuelBarrios `ListView` reuses Views from its first release, so i don't see what's your point

Comment: yes, but you have to do the "hard" work of implement the view holder by hand and that let you make mistakes.. in the other hand, the `RecyclerView`   has a better API and gives you less control over the algorithm, then you can focus on your real problem =)

Comment: @pskink BaseView is to map the view id with the good viewHolder, I followed this to do it  : http://ductranit.blogspot.fr/2012/10/generic-adapter-for-all-listview-in.html

Comment: @NahuelBarrios no, you don't have to implement view holder to make view recycling work, in fact no google's `BaseAdapters` adapter implement view holder pattern, see sources of `ArrayAdapter`, `CursorAdapter`, `SimpleAdapter` etc...

Comment: @flo3573358 just forget about view holder pattern: in 99% of cases its useless and only makes the problems like this, see: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html `"Given that we're measuring findViewById() in microseconds, even calling it a dozen times (with a reasonable number of Views) shouldn't cause performance issues."`, even google doesn't use it for its `ListView`'s adapters: see my comment above

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Json-ListView-Scroll-Cache)

Comment: @pskink thanks I didn't know about this, so what do you use to do it ?

Comment: @Mohit I will check this thanks